# Charles proxy outofmemory

Tags: ubuntu, out-of-memory, headless, charles-proxy

I have started charles proxy on remote machine on Ubuntu (20.04.6 LTS Focal Fossa) - charles --config /home/user/charles.config --headless
After some time logs show kill process due to Out of memory error

```
/usr/bin/charles: line 47: 475268 Killed                  $JAVA -Xmx1024M -Dcharles.config="~/.charles.config" -Djava.library.path="$CHARLES_LIB" -jar $CHARLES_LIB/charles.jar $*

 Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.

[9182.363s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "SocketHandler"
Exception in thread "com.xk72.proxy.ssl.a.Xsnk" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
```

I have seen official answer https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/charles-runs-out-of-memory/ - but I dont find specified files (charles.sh) searched different variants - files with name containing "charles"

where should I put -Xmx256m? Or are there other ways to increase charles proxy memory?

> > PS After increasing -xmx (in comments) still out of memory error, seems I need to clear session

Where is setting in headless mode in config file to clear session after it is saved? promptToClearSession true & saveLowMem true - does not help

Comment: Have you checked if `/usr/bin/charles` is a script (without .sh file ext)?

Comment: thank you it seems it is what I was looking for, I have increases xmx, it was 1024m - seems a lot                                                                                                                                                                                               `# Launch Charles
$JAVA \
    -Xmx3072M \
    -Dcharles.config="~/.charles.config" \
    -Djava.library.path="$CHARLES_LIB" \
    -jar $CHARLES_LIB/charles.jar \
    $*`

Comment: I have changed stack size - again stops with out of memory error - `/usr/bin/charles: line 47: 499215 Killed                  $JAVA -Xmx3072M -Dcharles.config="~/.charles.config" -Djava.library.path="$CHARLES_LIB" -jar $CHARLES_LIB/charles.jar $*`  May be it is necesasry to clear charles saves sessions? In config I have <promptToClearSession> true & <saveLowMem> true